# How to search between columns in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

i have two columns that store values(numbers), how do i select where my given number is between the values in the two columns?

Example

```
   `id | col1 | col2`  
    `1 | 20  | 50`  
    `2 | 200 | 400`  
    `3 | 500 | 650`
```

If I have a value of 25, how can i select records where the value of 25 is between them which in this case would be row 1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select * from mytable where 25 between col1 and col2;
```

Comment: Be sure to use EXPLAIN to check that the optimiser will use an appropriate index for this; it should ideally be able to range scan either col1 or col2

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

If you want to include col1 and col2 in the search:

```
select * from table where YOUR_NUM >= col1 and YOUR_NUM <= col2;
```

If not:

```
select * from table where YOUR_NUM > col1 and YOUR_NUM < col2;
```