# Need help pulling up this Mysql Query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple scenario but not getting it to work. I need to pull up a value for column 'fee' specified in Mysql Database according to two values.

[image: My Current table structure and values]

I want to get the value for 'fee' if I specify an amount between columns 'from' and 'to'
Example: if amount is 95, the value for row 'fee' should be 0.99.

I tried to use traditional method previously like below but now I would like MYSQL query method. Please help.

```
if ($amount < 100) {
$fee = '0.99';
}
else if ($amount > 100 && $amount < 500) {
$fee = '1.99';
}
else if ($amount < 500 && $amount < 1000) {
$fee = '2.99';
}
else if ($amount < 1000 && $amount < 10000) {
$fee = '4.99';
}
else if ($amount > 10000) {
$fee = '9.99';
}
```

A Sample PHP Code:

```
<?
include "dbconnect.php";

$post_amount = $_POST["amount"];

$sql = "SELECT fee FROM fees WHERE from < '$post_amount' AND to >     '$post_amount'     LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
$fee = $row["fee"];
}
echo "Posted Amount is $post_amount and Fee is $fee";

?>
```

Comment: use mysql case method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question, you need the SQL query.

You can use > and < signs:

```
"SELECT fee FROM tablename WHERE from < '$amount' AND to > '$amount' LIMIT 1"
```

Or you can use BETWEEN ([How to search between columns in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069963/how-to-search-between-columns-in-mysql)):

```
"SELECT fee FROM tablename where '$amount' BETWEEN from AND to LIMIT 1"
```

Two more things:

1. You'll need to sanitize $amount variable before using it in the query
2. **from** and **to** are [MySQL Reserve Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) and should not be used as column names

Comment: You stole my answer... editing your answer to incorporate mine is not a very nice thing to do.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I didn't steal your answer, I was editing mine before your's came up. No probs tho, I'll add a reference to your answer from mine :). And I did upvote your answer btw.

Comment: Tried this. It worked initially but i see an error Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ......

Comment: @ShaikatChakraborty Well that may happen in cases where there is no fee for that amount; boolean most likely mean there is no result.. Can you post the php code for the query and retrieving the resultset

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon Here is the php code. <?
include "dbconnect.php";

$post_amount = "100";

$sql = "SELECT fee FROM fees WHERE from < '$post_amount' AND to >     '$post_amount' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
$fee = $row["fee"];
}
echo "Posted Amount is $post_amount and Fee is $fee";

?>

Comment: The problem, as I mentioned above is your field names. the "WHERE from" part of your query will generate an SQL error since "from" is a mysql reserved word. Rename those 2 columns (from, to).. they will continue to cause errors since they are MySQL reserved words

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has an awesome operator called `BETWEEN`:

```
"SELECT `fee` FROM `table` WHERE ".floatval($amount)." BETWEEN `from` AND `to`"
```

Answer (score -1):

You just had problem in `> and <` all other things are fine in ur code there no need for other function to check it from database table.

I have checked it with this :

```
$amount = 250;

if ($amount < 100) {
    $fee = '0.99';
} else if ($amount > 100 && $amount < 500) {
    $fee = '1.99';
} else if ($amount > 500 && $amount < 1000) {
    $fee = '2.99';
} else if ($amount > 1000 && $amount < 10000) {
    $fee = '4.99';
} else if ($amount > 10000) {
    $fee = '9.99';
}

echo $fee;
```

Its works fine.

Comment: I cannot use this as I have multiple if conditions.... Using MYSQL would be great....

Comment: I am sorry about the $post_amount and $br_amount. Discard them. I am using $amount now....

Comment: I have added my answer what i have checked. Some time its useless to give extra load on database when you can do it with simple code.